# Escrita de funções MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Como é suposto escrever esta função no MATLAB? '1/(1+(1/(1+e(30*x))))'

Já tentei de mil maneiras e dá sempre erro. Alguém tem alguma ideia ?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olha essa anotação AeB é Ax10^B outro exemplo 6.022e23 equivale 6.022×10^23
Na sua 1/(1+(1/(1+e(30*x)))) equivale 1/(1+(1/(1+(faltou alguma coisa aqui)^(30*x))))